# Left module which cannot be made into a bimodule?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a noncommutative unital algebra, defined over $\mathbb{C}$ say. What is an example of a left $A$-module $M$ that does not admit a right  $A$-module structure giving $M$ the structure of a bimodule?

Comment: Perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348736/left-right-non-bimodule-examples answers your question.

Comment: @EFinat-S No, because that question only asks for the existence of some right $A$-module structure that is incompatible with the given left $A$-module structure. This question is asking for something much stronger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such examples are a plenty. You are asking about non-existence of an algebra map $A\rightarrow End_AM$. Take $A$ simple, at most countably dimensional, and a simple module ${}_{A}M$. Then $End_AM={\mathbb C}$. Bingo!